# MySQL join, query to return all the chapter titles and where available the grade of the user

Tags: mysql, join

I have my tables like that:

```
[users] [chapters] [exam_scores]
- id    - title    - fk_chapter
                   - fk_user
                   - grade
```

I need a query to return all the chapter titles and where available the grade of the user. Here is my try:

```
select chapters.title as Title, exam_scores.grade as Results
from users, exam_scores left join chapters
on chapters.id = exam_scores.fk_chapter
where exam_scores.fk_user = users.id and users.id = 15;
```

That one returns records if there is available grade, but not the rest of the chapters.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance guys. That query brought the solution:

    `SELECT c.title Title, s.grade Results`
    `FROM chapters c`
    `LEFT JOIN exam_scores s ON s.fk_chapter = c.id and s.fk_user = 15;`

Comment: Will work, but there is no room to add any user info as you don't join users table at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to get a list of all the chapters, regardless of whether or not there is a user score for the chapter.  Because of that, you want to SELECT from the chapters table.  Then, since you want a result for each chapter, you need to LEFT JOIN the exam_scores table so you will get records for rows that have scores, and records for scores that don't.  When using a natural join (`JOIN` or `FROM table, table2, table3`) records are only returned for which there are matching left and right values.

So, your query should look like this:

```
SELECT c.title Title, s.grade Results
FROM chapters c
LEFT JOIN exam_scores s ON s.fk_chapter = c.id
WHERE (s.fk_user = 15 OR s.fk_user IS NULL)
```

Notice, you don't need to even include the `users` table here, as you're not accessing any information for it.  Your query was joining the users table and then doing the `WHERE` clause on it's `id` key.  This is not required, unless you're getting data out of the users table.  If you do, in fact, need data out of the user's table, you'd LEFT JOIN it onto the exam_scores table like so:

```
SELECT c.title Title, s.grade Results, u.*
FROM chapters c
LEFT JOIN exam_scores s ON s.fk_chapter = c.id
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = s.fk_user
WHERE (s.fk_user = 15 OR s.fk_user IS NULL)
```

Hope that helps and sheds some light as to how you should structure your queries and JOINs better in the future.

**edit**: I edited my answer in response to your comment.  It makes complete sense why you wouldn't be getting responses without a grade attached, and here's why:

When you join the 2 tables together, they're being joined by the user id.  That's fine, because when the user id doesn't map over to the chapters table, you get a `NULL` value for the user id and grade.  However, since in our `WHERE` clause we are filtering for the user with id `15`, it filters out all the `NULL` values for the user columns.  So, to fix against this, you add an `OR` statement to your `WHERE` clause that says a user id of `NULL` is okay.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I still do not get the records that do not have a grade.

Comment: Oh, you know what. Oversight on my part. Updating my response now

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to `LEFT JOIN` twice in order to accomplish this.  As an aside, I'd also recommend avoiding the 'old style' join syntax (FROM table1, table2, table3 ...) as it's all too mess up these types of join.

```
select chapters.title as Title,
       exam_scores.grade as Results
from users
left join exam_scores
on exam_scores.fk_user = users.id
left join chapters
on chapters.id = exam_scores.fk_chapter
where users.id = 15;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, left join twice:

```
select 
    chapters.title as Title
    , exam_scores.grade as Results
from 
    users 
    left outer join exam_scores 
        on (users.id = exam_scores.fk_user)
    left outer join chapters 
        on (exam_scores.fk_chapter = chapters.id)
where
    users.id = 15
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Your approach works, but I need all the chapters' titles in every case, not only when I have grade.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT chapters.title AS Title, user_scores.grade AS Results
FROM chapters
LEFT JOIN  
       ( SELECT fk_chapter, grade FROM exam_scores
         JOIN users ON exam_scores.fk_user = users.id
         WHERE users.id = 15 ) user_scores 
ON chapters.id = user_scores.fk_chapter
```

Comment: In that case I do not get the records that have a grade from another user, due to the users.id IS NULL statement.

Comment: Its a condition for where, very much needed if you want to see chapters without a grade for the user. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, but if there is a record with a grade for another user for that chapter it will not be shown.

Comment: Changed a bit, should be ok now.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your query does not run. I posted my solution as a comment to my question.

Comment: I actually put some work into testing it and it runs fine. What error does it give you?

Comment: In your implementation with the `SELECT *` in the inner select I had `Duplicate column id`, while in your last version have `Column 'fk_chapter' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: I can't reproduce any of these errors. It may be some older mysql version that has problems resolving that. In that case just give exam_scores an alias and use it inside parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```sql
SELECT 
    chp. * , scr. * , usr. *
FROM 
    chapter AS chp
LEFT JOIN 
     scores AS scr ON scr.chapter_id = chp.id
LEFT JOIN 
     users AS usr ON usr.id = scr.user_id WHERE usr.id =15
```